# How to prepare yours for daily risky routine like flying planes?

Tags: psychology

Obviously you need certain personal traits to be a pilot or a surgeon. But if you make a mistake someone dies, you might be included. So I think there have to be studies on how to prepare before you fly a plain or attempt a surgery or go into a gunfight etc.

What would a psychologist recommend to prepare for a day like that. Especially if it is your day job and you have to be ready every day.

Example: https://youtube.com/shorts/Od6tPcGndK0

Comment: You should pick a better example than being a pilot. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that commercial pilots are more likely to be killed in an automobile crash while driving to or from the airport. Pilots *don't* view their jobs as dangerous or risky, so there's nothing for them to prepare for. ¶ "*if you make a mistake someone dies, you might be included*" is true every time you drive your car (a slight distraction and you move into oncoming traffic and have a head-on collision). How do *you* prepare yourself for that every day?

Comment: You're likely to encounter people with masters degrees and doctorates in psychology here. A diploma isn't very high on the academic scale. Perhaps you might read the [code of conduct](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: I would ask you to not assume that anyone who expresses a view here must be ignorant just because you've previously encountered ignorance in your life, nor because they do not possess a qualification that you recognise as appropriate. Enthusiastic amateurs who have achieved academic success in another subject and subsequently informally studied a second subject can be quite accomplished. Please see: [fallacy of illicit transference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_illicit_transference).

Comment: @BoppityBop asks "*BTW are you a pilot?*". Actually I *do* have a pilot's licence, but that's irrelevant. Any commercial flight where the pilot has to mentally prepare for the risk is not a flight you want to take. Every pilot I've known was extremely calm and took everything in stride, no preparation necessary.  Buses fall off cliffs more often than planes fall out of the sky. But both events are extremely rare, and no competent pilot would take off while having doubts about the success of the flight. I'm not criticizing the question, only the example. Try firefighters instead.